# Creating your own custom helpers with Freemarker?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

From my controller I set my Model and view like:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

mav.setView("index");

mav.addObject("user", user);
mav.addObject("someCollection", someCollection);

return mav;
```

Now I want to create a helper type object that will take the someCollection and the user object as parameters.

My helper function will output some HTML etc., is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write macros and directives using [FTL](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_misc_userdefdir.html) or [Java](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html), expose them to your templates and invoke them same way you normally do with built-in macros/directives.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prevents you from putting any Java object, e.g. a helper instance, to the model and then call a method of it using the syntax like this: `${helper.myMethod(arg)}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add logotype logotype1AsBase64.
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
@ModelAttribute("logotype1AsBase64")
public String getLogotype() 
        throws IOException {
    return logotypeService.getLogotype();
}
*/

@ModelAttribute
public void addAttributes(Model model) throws IOException {
    //...
    model.addAttribute("logotype1AsBase64", logotypeCacheServ.getImage("logotypeInEnglish1From20190101.png"));
    //...
}
```

Then to use it:

```
<img src="<#if locale == 'specificLocale'>${logotype1AsBase64}></#if>" alt="description for picture">
```

And the model attribute can contain more html other than base64 for logotype, if the setup is as such.